# MySQL: find row of users who have an entry on one date(time) but not the other date(time)

Tags: mysql

I have a group of users who have an entry on say the 1st of August. I want to find the users who have an entry on the 1st of August but didn't do anything on the 2nd of August.

Right now it's October so the event is long past.

My limited knowledge says:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2018-08-01 00:00:00' and '2018-08-01 23:59:59' AND NOT BETWEEN '2018-08-02 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-02 23:59:59';`

Though this gives a syntax error.

I suppose I should do a JOIN? Though I don't fully see how.

Comment: I just wanted to note that `SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE 
(order_date BETWEEN '2018-08-01 00:00:00' and '2018-08-01 23:59:59') 
AND 
(order_date  NOT BETWEEN '2018-08-02 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-02 23:59:59')` did the trick (the answer was deleted). Though I am also going to try the other answers.

Comment: I can't imagine how that would have done the trick. It's 100% synonymous with just `SELECT * FROM users WHERE (order_date BETWEEN '2018-08-01 00:00:00' and '2018-08-01 23:59:59')`

Comment: Let me try and see what the difference is

Comment: A WHERE is applied against a single record, one at a time. A single record that has an order_date on august 1st is DEFINITELY 100% not going to ALSO have an order_date on the 2nd because that's impossible. So your return with the `AND NOT BETWEEN` is going to give you all records with an `order_date` on the 1st regardless of whether that `user` had an `order_date` on the 2nd. A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or a `NOT EXISTS (<correlated subquery>` or a `NOT IN (<seperate SELECT statement>)` is the only way to go here.

Comment: Ah so it is basically the equivalent of `SELECT * FROM users WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2018-08-01 00:00:00' and '2018-08-01 23:59:59'`.

Answer (score 3):

A correlated subquery would work nicely for this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u
WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2018-08-01 00:00:00' and '2018-08-01 23:59:59' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE users.userid = u.uid WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2018-08-02 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-02 23:59:59')
```

Comment: 2 questions: shouldn't the `u.uid` not be `u.userid` as well? and shouldn't `WHERE order_date` not be `AND order_date`?

Answer (score 1):

As you asked, a JOIN is a classic solution:
you're looking on the same table, based on user_id and different order dates,
where the join returns null (weren't on August 2nd):

```
SELECT
*
FROM
users u1
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u1.user_id = u2.user_id AND u2.order_date BETWEEN '2018-08-02 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-02 23:59:59'
WHERE
u1.order_date BETWEEN '2018-08-01 00:00:00' and '2018-08-01 23:59:59'
AND u2.user_id IS NULL
```